# Stream cfcontent from an image?

Tags: coldfusion, cfimage

Let me just say at the top that I'm not sure I truly understand what cfcontent is doing... so bear with me if this is a stupid question.

I've been using cfcontent to stream images outside of my web root to the browser. I've decided that I now want to store the image in a variable, display it, have the ability to modify it, view those modifications, and only commit the changed variable when I'm sure I like the changes. I was thinking that I could use cfcontent to somehow stream the image from a variable, and then display, modify, re-display, and save that image from the variable. My original code was simply:

```
<img id="photoPlaceholder" 
    src="/#application.root_name#/administration/PhotoManagement/displayPhoto.cfm?thisImage=#thisImage#" 
    width="500px" />
```

and displayPhoto.cfm consisted of:

```
<cfcontent type = "image/*" 
    file = "myPathName" 
    deleteFile = "No" />
```

I see that I can read the file into a variable and stream from that variable:

```
<cffile action="readBinary" file="myPathName" variable="fileObject" />
<cfcontent type="image/*" variable="#fileObject#" />
```

but if I take the intermediate step of creating an image using

```
<cfimage source="fileObject" name="myImage" />
<cfcontent type="image/*" variable="#myImage#" />
```

then I get an attribute validation error.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ImageGetBlob()?](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7971.html)

> If you think about it - this makes sense. Image variables aren't
>   binary data in ColdFusion. While they may store binary data,
>   ColdFusion wraps up the data in a new "Image" variable type.

http://www.coldfusionjedi.com/index.cfm/2007/9/14/Serving-up-CFIMages-via-Image-Tags-and-a-NonCF-Friday-contest

If you're using CF9, you can try writing the image to the `RAM://` drive first, serve it, and delete from RAM.

Comment: Hm.. tried using <cfcontent variable=#ImageGetBlob(myImage)# /> but am getting server error that starts: "NetworkError: 500 The source file sho...rmine the image format. - http://localho" - and the most important bits are ellipsed. Still trying to figure out exactly what the error is.

Comment: Finally got it - the solution was to directly read the image into cfimage (d'oh!) , then use ImageGetBlob() as you suggested inside <cfcontent>. Thanks!!!